# Sharing folder with no password from WS2012 AD to non-domain computer

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, password, file-sharing

I have a network with a domain on Windows Server 2012 and a few clients with Windows 7 Pro and 2 with Windows 7 Home, so I can't add them to the domain.

On server I have a shared folder with software updates (not Windows updates).
On each computer I have software that is updated from this shared folder.
Problem is with non-domain computers. They can't see the shared folder.

I have tried:

1. I add new user named updates on server, set rights on this user to folder and write it to credentials window in client. It work, but I must do it manually
2. Second way - this isn't look good for me - I enable Guest account on server then I add permission for guest in Share / Security od shared folder.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Using the builtin FTP server would be a good fit for anonymous, read-only access.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to enable guest, your choices are:

1. Manually or scriptomatically map the share with different credentials.
2. Create an account on the machines with Windows 7 home that uses a username/password combination that's identical to a domain account and do all updating from that account.